# Symfony2/Silex middlewares

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am using silex to create an api and my routes look something similar to this:

```
$api = $app['controllers_factory'];
$users = $app['controllers_factory'];

$users->match('/', UsersController::action);

$api->mount('/users', $users);
$app->mount('/api', $api);
```

So the route would be baseurl/api/users

What I want to do now is to attach a before() to the $api controller group and enforce validation for the api, so any link prefixed with /api/...users, posts
would require validation.
But it seems that is not the way it works, when i put a before to the $api, it only works for the root of /api, not api/users or api/posts or api/categories, they require their own middlewares.

So my question is : how can I enforce everything after baseurl/api/... to require validation in a Silex enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `before()` to your `$app` instance (see http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#before-middleware).

And test the `$request` object to see if authentication is required.

You could also use the [`SecurityServiceProvider`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html), but that may be overkill depending on your use case.

Comment: that would work but what if I wanted to add an extra route for something else, that would get validated also baseurl/admin

Comment: Test `$request->getRequestUri()`, ie `if (preg_match('#^/(api|other)#', $request->getRequestUri())) { .. }`